# Does "Firebase Unity SDK" correspond to "Notification Channels" which is a new feature of Android Oreo?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, sdk

I think that the following is necessary to push notification to Android Oreo's terminal.
· Register "Notification Channel"
· Create "Notification" and register to "Notification Channel"

How can I do the above processing using "Firebase Unity SDK"?

Comment: I think you'd just make the normal notification API calls? Why do you need to go through the Firebase SDK or the Unity SDKs? What do you mean "correspond to" ?